# difference in CDFs and pdfs of joint distribution of two random variables

Tags: independence, cumulative-distribution-function

We know that the joint probability function of two ***independent random variables*** is just the product of their respective pdfs. On the same lines, .can we say that if we **multiply the cumulative density functions(CDFs) of those two random variables**, the resulting function will be the CDF of joint distribution? Like f1 and f2 are the two pdfs of the independent random variable. The joint pdf will simply be f1*f2. If F1 and F2 are their CDFs.Can we say that F=F1*F2 represents their joint CDF?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: Thanks Adrian.Can you please suggest me any text regarding this concept which I can see.

Comment: any book or any other source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. Its just a simple exercise:
Suppose $X$ is a random variable distributed according to pdf $g$ and cdf $G$. Similarly $Y$ is a random variable distributed according to pdf $h$ and pdf $H$. Let $f$ be the pdf of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

$X$ and $Y$ are independent: i.e. $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ for all $(x,y)\in X\times Y$.

Then we have the following:
\begin{align}
F(x,y) &= Pr(X\leq x, Y\leq y)\\ 
& = \int_{X\leq x}\int_{Y\leq y}f(s,t)dtds\\
& = \int_{X\leq x}\int_{Y\leq y}g(s)h(t)dtds\\
& = \int_{X\leq x}g(s)H(y)ds\\
& = G(x)H(y)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank You so much Shomak for explaining so nicely and clearly with proof.

Comment: No problem at all. The second last equality secretly employs Fubini's theorem, in case anyone is wondering.